# Increase the speed of the motorbike by mistake(by throttling it more than you should)

Tags: spoken-english

[image]

If someone **just learnt to ride a bike and is not very good** at controlling the speed. That person (by accident) increases the speed by twisting the throttle  towards him/her more than (s)he should. So what will be a natural way to express this **"throttling the throttle and , increasing the speed that may make you fall down due to a sudden increase in speed"**? So  how can it be expressed? The person "accelerated more than (s)he should, because that person couldn't control the speed (how my should the throttle be throttled)

Comment: I don't think there's a special phrase for such situation and you'd need to explain all of it properly, the whole action.

Comment: Wasn't gentle / progressive enough with the throttle / didn't throttle on smooth(ly) enough / jerked the throttle / gave it too much welly. Anyway, if your man fell off, the problem is more likely that he wasn't slipping the clutch...

Answer (score 2):

You could say that they **overrevved** (can likely also be written as **over revved** or **over-revved**) the motorbike.

> To rev (an engine or vehicle) too much.
>   <sub>https://www.yourdictionary.com/overrev</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Close to what you had would be: "Opened the throttle too far" or "... too hard" or "... too fast"

The second part would involve "unexpected/involuntary wheelie" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One might refer to a new rider having **poor throttle control**, as it works both ways, for too little or too much acceleration, but also works well for a rider who is just heavy handed with the throttle.

Too little throttle often leads to **kangaroo fuel** (or variants thereof) where the vehicle jumps forward then almost stalls before jumping forward again, these kangaroos in the fuel tank are likely to cause a rider to come adrift.